# WhatsApp 2 step verification code being asked frequently

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is it normal that Whatsapp keep asking for your two step verification PIN in a certain frequency? Like once a week for example. I noticed this behavior on my phone. Is something to worry about or it's normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000021/) I would like to believe this is normal, for security reasons and **to prevent one from forgetting their PIN**

> Two-step verification is an optional feature that adds more security
>   to your account. When you have two-step verification enabled, any
>   attempt to verify your phone number on WhatsApp must be accompanied by
>   the six-digit PIN that you created using this feature.

and that...

> To help you remember your PIN, **WhatsApp will periodically ask you to
>   enter your PIN.** There is no option to disable this without disabling
>   the two-step verification feature.

Comment: I find this really dumb because I use a password manager, No matter how many times it asks for the PIN I'll just never remember it (heck I don't even know it in the first place).

Comment: @AlvinWong Meta are pretty dumb in general when it comes to security. You'd think a _big tech_ company of _that scale_ would know what works and what doesn't.